# Create json object in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to create a json object in AngularJS
My code is as below

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){

    var dCol = file.columns[i].value;
        var dRow = file.rows[i].value;
        $scope.fileContents.push({ dCol: dRow });

}
```

But the value of dCol is not reflecting. It is taking dCol as a string "dCol".

Can someone please help me out. I am fairly new to angularJS. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
$scope.fileContents.push({ dCol: dRow });
```

please do this:

```
var tmpObj = {};
tmpObj[dCol] = dRow;
$scope.fileContents.push(tmpObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because `dCol` is a key and  a key is always a string in a JS object;

try this:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   var obj ={};
   var dCol = file.columns[i].value;
   var dRow = file.rows[i].value;

    obj[dCol]=dRow;

    $scope.fileContents.push(obj);

}
```

---

if you like a more synthetic approach , this should work to:

```
$scope.fileContents.push({ [dCol]: dRow });
```

Comment: In that case, how can I use the value in file.columns[i].value as a key?

Answer (score 0):

Are youa bit confused with the differences between variables and object properties, 
in your example you are adding a property named dCol to the object pushed into fileContents...

by the way, 
if the dCol variable is a string you can do something like that:

```
var item = {}; item[dcol] = dRow; fileContents.push(item);
```

if the variable dCol isn't a string, you may consider to add it to the object:

```
fileContents.push({ "dCol": dCol, "dRow": dRow });
```